# ¿Cómo generar un alfanumerico que siga un formato de acuerdo al año ingresado en mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Necesito crear en *ASP.NET* un *WebForm* que contenga un número de folio con el formato `0000/yyyy`. Donde el primer registro ingresado sea, por ejemplo, `0001/2019`, y aumente en `1` para cada nuevo registro.

Pero cuando cambie el año, se reinicie el folio a `1`. Por ejemplo `0001/2020`, `0001/2021`.

¿Es posible resolver esto mediante una consulta en *MySQL*?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Se puede hacer de montones de formas. intentaste algo y tuviste algun problema en particular?

Answer (score 0):

No tienes en la tabla una `columna compuesta`, se supone que deben ser dos columnas separadas, una para el `año` y otra para el `numero secuencial`, despues como la muestras al usuario es indistinto.

Desde la consulta podras usar

```
SELECT MAX(secuencial) FROM NombreTabla WHERE año = @año
```

Indicando el año en que estas consultando tendras el valor del ultimo numero de secuencial, para insertar solo le sumas uno

Para recuperar el valor el codigo con `ado.net` seria como esto

```
int maxsec = 0;

using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    cn.Open();

    string query = "SELECT MAX(secuencial) FROM NombreTabla WHERE anio= ?anio";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?anio", año);

    maxsec = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

}
```

Comment: si genere en mysql una tabla con llave primaria compuesta,  una columna le puse id y la otra año estoy intentando algo asi pero marca error, en el end if no se si estoy haciendo bien o si funcione.

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`residuos`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(
_año int,
_nombre varchar(200),
_peso int,
_cantidad int
)
BEGIN
IF _idBoleta=0 and _año=max(año) THEN
Insert into rstmanifiesto(año,residuo,Cantidad,peso)
values (_año,_nombre,_cantidad,_peso);

 if _año>max(año) THEN
    set año=0;
Insert into rstmanifiesto(año,residuo,Cantidad,peso )
values (_año,_nombre,_cantidad,_peso);
else 
 UPDATE rstmanifiesto
        SET
        _nombre=nombre,
        _peso=peso,
        _cantidad = Cantidad
        where _año=año;
END IF;
END

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez deberias haber editado la respuesta y agregado el codigo del procedure con algo de formato, como comentario esta complicado de entender

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez no se que es eso del   `if _año>max(año) THEN`, el MAX se usa como parte de un SELECT, ademas porque no envias eso desde codigo .net en lugar de querer resolverlo dentro del procedure, que este solo inserte lo que envias desde codigo net

Comment: si es que no me acordaba como darle formato aqui, de hecho se me ha hecho mas facil realizar dentro del procedure que en el codigo, tengo solo como 2 procedimientos en el codigo

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez en los comentarios no puedes dar formato, por eso comente que edites la pregunta y agregues esto que comentas del procedure. Dentro del procesure no creo que el Max() se use de la forma como lo estas implementando. No conozco mucho de MySql, pero el max se usa junto a un select

Comment: jajaj si ya vi marca un error, e investigue y el error es cundo uso un procedimiento en un lugar incorrecto como el max dentro de un if

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que tienes un campo de **fecha** (como suele ser común, puede que sea formato UNIX o no, véase https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

Contando que utilizamos MySQL, podemos utilizar **YEAR()** para saber el año actual, y para saber el año del último registro. Si este se encuentra en formato **UNIX** se puede utilizar **FROM_UNIXTIME()** para convertirlo a human-readable.

Para comprobarlo, si hacemos esto con el día de hoy:

```
SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1569432149))
```

Por ende sabemos obtener dos valores para comparar en un **WHERE**.

Así que conluimos con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tu_tabla WHERE YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tu_fecha))
```

**IMPORTANTE**: Si la fecha está guardada en formado dd-mm-yyyy o similar, tienes que eliminar **FROM_UNIXTIME()** de la consulta.

Esto te devolverá el número de hoja. Si quieres que empiece por 1, tendrás que sumar 1.

Comment: si tengo una tabla con llave primaria compuesta, uno con id y el otro llamado anio

Comment: Quedaría SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tu_tabla WHERE YEAR(CURDATE()) = anio

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente select devuelve el valor 0001/2019.

```
SELECT CONCAT (LPAD(1, 4, 0), "/", YEAR(CURDATE()))
```

Si quieres generar el siguiente folio solo obten el ultimo id registrado de tu tabla, sumale 1 y sustituyelo en el primer argumento de la función **LPAD**

```
SELECT CONCAT (LPAD(YOUR_LAST_ID, 4, 0), "/", YEAR(CURDATE()))
```

Si el año va a ser ingresado por el usuario puedes hacer un Stored Procedure